# c# check if a class has defined enum

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class like this

```
public class SomeClass {
public enum Status { A,B,C}
}
```

I want to do

```
bool enumExists = MysteryMethod("SomeClass.Status");
```

What goes inside MysteryMethod ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are types themselves.

Nested types are named with + between the container class and the type name

Therefore, the name of the mystery method would be Type.GetType

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public enum Status
    {

    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType("Lab.SomeClass+Status", false);
        bool isEnum = t.IsEnum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); 
var typ = asm.GetType("SomeClass+Status")
var enumExists = (typ != null && typ.IsEnum);
```

Trick is to put + after class name when you GetType.